# How to check for NULL when mapping nested JSON?

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I'm trying to map a nested JSON to the model object, the problem is when it returns null, it will break all the code, I want to check if null do something but not break the app.

**THE JSON FILE:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 53,
        "date": "2018-12-28T08:51:11",
        "title": {
            "rendered": "this is for featured"
        },
        "content": {
            "rendered": "\n<p><g class=\"gr_ gr_3 gr-alert gr_spell gr_inline_cards gr_run_anim ContextualSpelling\" id=\"3\" data-gr-id=\"3\">sdafkj</g> <g class=\"gr_ gr_10 gr-alert gr_spell gr_inline_cards gr_run_anim ContextualSpelling ins-del multiReplace\" id=\"10\" data-gr-id=\"10\">kj</g> <g class=\"gr_ gr_16 gr-alert gr_spell gr_inline_cards gr_run_anim ContextualSpelling ins-del multiReplace\" id=\"16\" data-gr-id=\"16\">asd</g> <g class=\"gr_ gr_18 gr-alert gr_spell gr_inline_cards gr_run_anim ContextualSpelling\" id=\"18\" data-gr-id=\"18\">kadjsfk</g> kljadfklj sd</p>\n",
            "protected": false
        },
        "excerpt": {
            "rendered": "<p>sdafkj kj asd kadjsfk kljadfklj sd</p>\n",
            "protected": false
        },
        "author": 1,
        "featured_media": 54,
        "_links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "https://client.kurd.app/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/53"
                }
            ],

        },
        "_embedded": {
            "author": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "hooshyar",

                }
            ],
            "wp:featuredmedia": [
                {
                    "id": 54,

                    "source_url": "https://client.kurd.app/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/icannotknow_22_12_2018_18_48_11_430.jpg",
                    }
                    ]
}
]
```

CODE FOR MAPPING TO OBJECT:

```
  featuredMediaUrl = map ["_embedded"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["source_url"];
```

The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null [0] which sometimes returns null ;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following my comment I suggest you to use a code generation library to parse `JSON` to `JSON Models`.

Read [this article](https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries) that explain you how to use (for example) the [json_serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable) package.

Such libraries *takes all the dirty job of generate all the boilerplate code* to create your Model classes and they take care of `null` values as mandatory or not.

For example if you annotate a class Person like that:

```
@JsonSerializable(nullable: true)
class Person {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final DateTime dateOfBirth;
  Person({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth});
  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);
}
```

with (`nullable: true`) the dart class of your model will skip the null value fields.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Because I'm eager of technology I've given [quicktype](https://quicktype.io) tool (suggested by Christoph Lachenicht)  a try with your example.

I've prepared a [mock api](https://www.shadowsheep.it/so/53962129/testjson.php) and a file `example.json` providing the JSON you've posted. I've taken only one element, not the array. And you can have a look here [example.json](https://www.shadowsheep.it/so/53962129/example.json).

After installin QuickType I've generate the model class for this json:

```
quicktype --lang dart --all-properties-optional example.json -o example.dart
```

Pay attention here to tha cli parameter `--all-properties-optional` that create null checks for missing fields.

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id == null ? null : id,
    "date": date == null ? null : date,
    "title": title == null ? null : title.toJson(),
    "content": content == null ? null : content.toJson(),
    "excerpt": excerpt == null ? null : excerpt.toJson(),
    "author": author == null ? null : author,
    "featured_media": featuredMedia == null ? null : featuredMedia,
    "_links": links == null ? null : links.toJson(),
    "_embedded": embedded == null ? null : embedded.toJson(),
};
```

Then I've used the Example class in `example.dart`

```
var jsonExampleResponse =
    await http.get('https://www.shadowsheep.it/so/53962129/testjson.php');
print(jsonExampleResponse.body);

var exampleClass = exampleFromJson(jsonExampleResponse.body);
print(exampleClass.toJson());
```

And all went fine.

**N.B.** 
Of course when you use this class you have to check if its fields are empty before using them:

```
print(exampleClass.embedded?.wpFeaturedmedia?.toString());
```

That's all. I hope to have put you in the rigth direction.

Comment: It seems like all that boilerplate could be simplified as `"content" : content?.toJson(),`.  I wonder why they're doing it the hard way.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Actually I’ve realized I’ve post the serialization code of the generated class and not the deserialization part ^_^.  Btw for the serialization part it seems okay to check content before calling toJson. Anyway I didn’t drill down in the generated class. My point was to use just one code generation library (the one you prefere) intead of mapping the json by hand.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple solution:

```
safeMapSearch(Map map, List keys) {
  if (map[keys[0]] != null) {
    if (keys.length == 1) {
      return map[keys[0]];
    }
    List tmpList = List.from(keys);
    tmpList.removeAt(0);
    return safeMapSearch(map[keys[0]], tmpList);
  }
  return null;
}
```

use:

```
featuredMediaUrl = safeMapSearch(map, ["_embedded","wp:featuredmedia",0,"source_url"]);
```

The function iterates recursively on the `map` with the keys supplied in `keys`, if a key is missing it will return `null` otherwise it will return the value of the last key.

Comment: Loved this approach. Exactly what I wanted. I just wanted to get value from nested json but I don't wanted to serialize and create class from it. This is the perfect solution.

Comment: But it gives error when using index like 0. I got this error " type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' " . Is there any solution for that ?