# Flutter: how to decode this complex JSON string

Tags: json, flutter, decode

From my REST API a JSON string is received as

> {"total":"30","results":[
>   {"ID":"1809221034017","DATE":"2018-09-22","REG":"(E9)","START":"10:40","END":"10:48"},
>   {"ID":"1809221337250","DATE":"2018-09-22","REG":"(E4)","START":"13:43","END":"13:57"},
>   {"ID":"1809161032213","DATE":"2018-09-16","REG":"(E1)","START":"11:04","END":"11:13"}]}

The total field tells me that the database contains in total 30 records, the requested data (only 3 rows) is included in the results section.

I need to parse the data, so I can show the results in ListView.  I managed to do this with a simple JSON string, but not with this complex JSON string. Unfortunately I am not able to change the output of the web service since this is hosted by a 3rd party.

Any help, or a code example, is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show your tried code? what you done so far to decode this json?

Comment: complex? `results` is just an array of maps... so you can acces it like: `results[0]["ID"]`

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962129/how-to-check-for-null-when-mapping-nested-json/53962541#53962541) read all the comments too.

Comment: And look also my answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

Read first my [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962129/how-to-check-for-null-when-mapping-nested-json/53962541#53962541).

Then I suggest you to use a class generation library like [quicktype](https://quicktype.io/).

Using quick type for example you can easily and automatically genearate your moidel class in dart using your JSON. [Here the generated file](https://www.shadowsheep.it/so/53968769/my_json_class.dart).

```
quicktype --lang dart --all-properties-optional https://www.shadowsheep.it/so/53968769/testjson.php -o my_json_class.dart
```

Then use it in code:

```
import 'my_json_class.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var response = await http.get('https://www.shadowsheep.it/so/53968769/testjson.php');
    var myClass = MyJsonClass.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    for(var result in myClass.results.toList()) {
       print(result?.id);
    }
```

[image]

**N.B.** If you'll master a code generator library, then you'll be able to parse any type of JSON coming from a `REST API` and you'll have more time for fun.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Your JSON in proper format]
So here we can see that there is a JSON object having two values a JSON array and a total number.Sometimes the internet services don't return the full value but only a part due to network issues.
So now in the array we have number of results objects with an ID,DATE,REG,START,END.
If you format the JSON you will decode it easily.

Comment: Thanks of your view. It is straight forward, but I didn't saw it in this way. I was too much focussing on parsing the results array only.  This will work

Comment: In your case you have an array of maps for results field. Something like List< Map<String, dynamic> > every map in your list will have the keys: ID, DATE, REG, START, END and the respective values.

Comment: You can get this view easily here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com Have I been able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend this article: https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51

```
 class Result
            {
               String id ;
                 String date;
                 String reg ;
                 String start;
                 String end ;

            Result({this.date,this.end,this.id,this.reg,this.start});

            factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {

             return new Result(
               id: parsedJson['ID'],
               date: parsedJson['DATE'],
               reg: parsedJson['REG'],
               start: parsedJson['START'],
               end: parsedJson['END'],
             );
          }
            }

             class Results
            {
                 String total;
                 List<Result> results;

                Results({this.results, this.total});
                factory Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
                var list = parsedJson['results'][] as List;
                return new Results(
                total: parsedJson['total'],
                results: list.map((i) => Result.fromJson(i)).toList());
            }}
```